# How do I use the outputof one linux function and pass it to another linux function

Tags: linux

Manual steps.

1. I run command that lists data about my applications. There are over 1200 commands/jobs.
2. One of the lines has a location where logs can be found. I want to run a "more" on this file location.

Is this possible with Unix scripting using one function or with one function calling another function?

Comment: It absolutely is, please share some sample of this `command number 1` output that includes the `log file` line, as well as what that `log file` is that we are to identify (that you want to `more`). We can help you get that piece from the output and pipe it to `more`.

Comment: This is the type of thing that should be explained in any shell scripting tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

Yes!

There's quite a few ways to combine operations! There's pipes, that let you send the output of one command to another command. There's commands like `grep` (search), `sed` (for find/replace) and `awk` (computation, and more) to help you process the output (and send it to some other programs with pipes). There's operations like in-line evaluation (`$(...)`) to help you run a command and give it to another command as an argument.

Concretely, lets say your program `list-my-data` produces output for your program. It looks like this (stuff after `$` is what you type, rest is the output):

```
$ list-my-data  
line 1
line 2
line 3
log file: /path/to/a/file.log
line 5
....
line 100000
```

You can extract the line the contains the log file by piping (`|`) it to `grep` and telling `grep` what to search for:

```
$ list-my-data | grep 'log file:'
log file: /path/to/a/file.log
```

From this, you can extract the path to the log file by piping the output to `sed` and asking `sed` to remove the extra stuff in the line:

```
$ list-my-data | grep 'log file:' | sed -e 's|log file: ||'
/path/to/a/file.log
```

You can now pass this line to `more` (or better, `less`) by evaluating it and passing it as an argument:

```
$ less $(list-my-data | grep 'log file:' | sed -e 's|log file: ||')
```